# Jquery Ui dialog on form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, user-interface, submit, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to stop jquery ui dialogs from popping up after 1 condition is met on form submit. One dialog per event is what I'm looking for. Kind of a break if a condition is met. Currently all dialogs come up after one is closed. I tried stopPropagation and stopImmediatePropagation with no effect. My code follows:

```
    $('#myForm').on('submit',function(e){
     if ($("#tramA").is(':checked') && !$('.tramAChecked:checked').length) {
                   $( "#tramA-message" ).dialog({
                    modal: true,
      draggable: false,
      resizable: false,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
});
e.preventDefault();
}

     if ($("#tramB").is(':checked') && !$('.tramBChecked:checked').length) {
     $( "#tramB-message" ).dialog({
                    modal: true,
      draggable: false,
      resizable: false,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
 });
e.preventDefault();
} 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tramB-message" title="Warning">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:3px 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    You selected "Tram B hall" but did not select a tram option!
  </p>
  </div>
  <div id="tramA-message" title="Warning">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:3px 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    You selected "Tram A hall" but did not select a tram option!
  </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your `.each()` loops. They're just checking the same thing each time through, not doing anything with `i` or `this`.

Comment: You don't need to use `$(function ...)` inside an event handler. That only has to be wrapped around the top-level jQuery code.

Comment: If you only want to display the dialog once, set a variable outside the loop to `true`. Before displaying the dialog, check if it's set. If it is, display the dialog and set the variable to false.

Comment: Also, if you `return false` from the `.each()` function, that will stop it from looping.

Comment: don't i have to iterate over all the checkboxes to see what their state is to fire the function? using each

Comment: @Barmar Does this work with multiple dialogs and functions?

Comment: Yes, but you're not checking their state, you're checking the state of the same `#tramA` element each time.

Comment: You probably need `if ($(this).is(":checked"))`

Comment: True, but aren't I also checking the state of my sub checkboxes in the targeted div too? I'm a bit confused. Or not div but all elements with the same class.

Comment: No, you're not. You're not using `$(this)` anywhere, so the selectors access all the elements that match, not just the ones in the target DIV.

Comment: Running code inside an event handler does not automatically restrict selections to the target.

Comment: I'd like to give @Barmar credit for advice on refining my code. Not sure how to do that on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

changing e.preventDefault(); to return false; did the trick.